# Prevent changing read status by delegates in Outlook

Tags: permissions, delegates, outlook

Is there a way to prevent mailbox delegates to change the read status on emails in outlook?

we have an ordering system in place that checks the mailbox every 10 minutes for unread mails and then marks them as read when the order is processed. We want delegates to monitor the mailbox to see if mails are staying unread (which would indicate that they are not processing). But we don't want the delegates to accidentally "read" the emails otherwise the order processing will ignore that order.

Comment: There are other ways to flag the order as being processed. Prefix the subject. Add a category. Add a User Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, mailboxes store read state on the per message basis. You can deliver the messages to a mail-enabled Public Folders store instead - PF store stores read status on the per message per user basis.

Comment: ok, fair enough, is there a way for delegates to ONLY see how many unread mails there are without being able to look at the mails?

Comment: You can look at the number next to the folder name in the tree view. Or you can turn the preview pane off (which by default narks the messages as read).